# Installing the AWS Command Line Interface on Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I required pip before installing aws cli so I tried to install pip by using command.

**curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py**

As soon as I run  this command it starts the timer and after every 2 minutes and approx 6 seconds it stops and terminates displaying the message.

[Please open this image to see the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YbZ7.png)

What does this error indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that you either don't have access or have limited access to the address https://bootstrap.pypa.io.

If this is an EC2 instance, make sure you are allowing outbond traffic for the port 443 (https).

Comment: Sir I have added one more rule i.e for the port 443(https) in the inbound rule of that security group which is attached to the EC2 instance. By adding the rule in the inbound rule it will automatically get added to outbound rule since security groups are stateful in nature.The problem is that I am still getting an error after adding the https rule for the port 443.

Comment: Problem solved: When I added port 443 in outbound rule it worked but when I added 443 rule in inbound rule it did not worked. Why is this happening since we all know that security groups are stateful in nature that is we do not explicitly define all rules in the outbound rules.

Comment: AFAIK, if a security group allows an inbound port to be open, the outbound port will automatically allow traffic out as a response to a new incoming connection. But it will not allow a new connection from the instance to the outbound port.

Comment: Sorry sir but I am not able to get your last line. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

If you don't have an outbound rule, you won't be able to start a new outbound connection, no matter which inbound rules you have.

Comment: What stateful means to the inbound rules, for example, is that, once a inbound connection is made, all traffic will be allowed through that connection. Let's say you have a web server running on 443 and you have only a inbound rule for this port. From the outside, you will be able start a connection to the server, send (inbound traffic) and receive (outbound traffic) data. But you won't be able to start a connection from the instance/server to any other external service using 443.

Comment: OK sir,This is quite understandable. Just wanted to confirm that I understood it correct I am just repeating what you just explained....So if I am accessing the server which has only inbound rules suppose for http(port-80) , the server will still be able to respond even if it does not has an outbound rule for port 80.But if I am on the server and I am requesting an external service from the server then I have to explicitly define the outbound rule .Is it correct?

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.

Comment: @NikhilBansal no problem. I would appreciate an upvote on the answer :)